# Python copy to clipboard the content of a variable

Tags: python, copy, paste

I have a variable that stores text that the user types in a dialogue box. 
I need to copy this text and then paste it in another field (to make a search)

I tried pyperclip but it works only with plain text, not with variables. Here is the code just for the dialogue box and **e** is my variable.

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()

e.focus_set()


def callback():
    print(e.get())  # This is the text I want to use later


b = Button(master, text="insert", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()


mainloop()
```

Comment: why do you need to copy and paste it?

Comment: I'm making some automations using selenium

Comment: ok, if the user inputs text why cant pyperclip work with it?

Comment: this text is stored in a variable. pyperclip does not read the variable content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create tkinter string to store this value, i have included this in your code below.

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

estring = StringVar(master)

e = Entry(master, textvariable = estring,)
e.pack()

e.focus_set()




def callback():
    print(estring.get())  # This is the text I want to use later


b = Button(master,  text="insert", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()


mainloop()
```

Below is the exmaple using pyperclip, to copy the input text to the clipboard.

```
from tkinter import *
import pyperclip

master = Tk()

estring = StringVar(master)

e = Entry(master, textvariable = estring,)
e.pack()

e.focus_set()


def callback():
    pyperclip.copy(estring.get())

b = Button(master,  text="copy", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()


mainloop()
```

Once text is entered and the copy button is pressed the text is now on the clipboard.

Comment: thank you for yout time. shouldn't I use anything for the clipboard? it doesn't seem to work

Comment: no worries, pyperclip should now work with the string output

Comment: so, StringVar cannot be used as a type in pyperclip. I used str (estring = str(master)) and then pyperclip.copy(estring). It tries to work but only a dot is somehow appeared when i paste!

Comment: you need to .get() the StringVar - i have updated my answer above with a second example with pyperclip

Comment: oh thank you, that was missing. now it works great. thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work in your context?

```
import pyperclip

test = "Hugo"
pyperclip.copy(test)
print(pyperclip.paste())
```

Comment: thank you, I need to load text from a variable (input of a dialogue box)

Comment: And where is that code? Does the "reading input from dialogue box" stuff work? Can you print the text you read?